# Switching Size Classes Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, size-classes

I just built the UI of my iOS 8 App using two Size Classes (Any/Any,Regular/Any).
Now I have realized that I need the Any/Any configuration for every device and orientation except iPhones in landscape (here I would like to use the configuration of Regular/Any).

How can I copy the configuration from Regular/Any to Any/Compact and delete this configuration in the Size Class Regular/Any?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way, but how I've done it is:

- Go into Any/Compact
- De-install/deactivate all constraints for the Any/Compact size class.

[image]

[image]

- Go into Regular/Any
- Change all of its constraints to be installed on A/C and deinstall/deactivate from R/A.

It's manual labor, but it gets the job done.